# Can we configure Services in SharePoint online 2016

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

Want to know can we configure Services in Office 365 SharePoint Online 2016. Like Search Services, User Profile Services etc..

Answer (score 0):

This is all done for you by the larger multi tenant service in SharePoint online. Many administrative tasks are no longer required in this software-as-a-service model, including core service provisioning.